# Tools menu missing the Script editor menu item in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

On my iMac, Google Sheets does not appear to have the 'Script Editor' as an option on the Tools menu. Not sure if I am missing some setting on the iMac.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please share more details like name and version of the operative system and web browser that you have tried as a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Please pay attention to correct capitalisation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if there is an **Extensions** menu in the menu bar, and look there if it is present.

In the event you are using an account that is part of a Google Workspace Domain, your domain administrator may have disabled the script editor. Talk to your domain administrator to see if it can be made available again.

Comment: The Extensions menu had an 'Apps Script' option. This should hopefully get me started.